# C++ wrapper for protobuf

Tags: c++, design-patterns, wrapper, protocol-buffers

stackoverflowers,

I'm not so familiar with C++ so my question could be related to bad design or somewhat.

Anyway:

I have a protobuf-generated class with multiple nesting and I want to somehow wrap all of this in graceful manner.

Proto:

```
message ChunkConfigInfo
{
  required uint32 max_size = 1 [default = 65536];
}

message BundleConfigInfo
{
  required uint32 max_payload_size = 2 [default = 0x200000];
  optional string default_compression_method = 3 [default = "lzma"];
}

message ConfigInfo
{
  required ChunkConfigInfo chunk = 1;
  required BundleConfigInfo bundle = 2;
}
```

That definitions was translated by protobuf to ConfigInfo class that will have at least following methods:

```
inline const ::BundleConfigInfo& bundle() const;
inline ::BundleConfigInfo* mutable_bundle();
[..]
inline const ::ChunkConfigInfo& chunk() const;
inline ::ChunkConfigInfo* mutable_chunk();
```

BundleConfigInfo have following methods:

```
inline const ::std::string& default_compression_method() const;
inline void set_default_compression_method(const ::std::string& value);
```

And so on.

Currently I could use them like that:

```
// brain-compiled code
ConfigInfo configInfo;
configInfo.mutable_bundle()->set_default_compression_method( .. ); //set value
string compression( configInfo.bundle().default_compression_method() ); //get value
```

What I want to achieve:

I want to have a single wrapper for all of the ChunkConfigInfo and BundleConfigInfo members that could perform some validation (based on types) so I could use them in following way:

```
// brain-compiled code
ConfigInfoWrapper configInfo;
// please note that only single method is used for assigning and getting values:
configInfo.bundle()->default_compression_method( .. ); //set value
string compression( configInfo.bundle()->default_compression_method() ); //get value
```

Or something similar.

I could implement this wrapper using some code generator that would generate all appropriate methods but this approach had one serious drawback: I need to maintain protobuf definitions together with the code generator definitions.

Another approach is to implement protobuf plugin but this seems to be vulnerable to protobuf internal changes.

Could it be implemented somehow using C++ templates and preprocessor features?

I would be very grateful for any advices on how to achieve that without protobuf plugins and code generators.

Comment: I really don't think this wrapping is worth the effort. With the C++ code generated by protobuf, you can tell the compiler (and yourself) whether you want to modify the bundle (by calling `mutable_bundle()`) or not (by calling `bundle()`). If you want to add validation, you'll have to write that code by hand. Otherwise just learn to live with having to call functions named `set_...` :) (although it can be a bit of a pain to remember that `mutable_foo()` returns a pointer whereas `foo()` returns a reference).

Comment: Unless this code is an example, `default_compression_method` should really be an enum and not a string. Otherwise you'll have to handle values like "yogurt" :)

Comment: @Bulletmagnet default_compression_method is already validated in other part of code that wasn't related to protobuf. enum really seems to be better solution but idc about that right now.